# EDIT: variables still go into db without retrieving them; POST displaying variables in url PHP

Tags: php, database, post

This still works even with the corrected form method and without retrieving the values on the insert.php page. Why?

```
  <!doctype html>

 <html>

<head>
<title></title>
</head

<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br>
    Username:  <input type="text" name="uname" /><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"/><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php

 $con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
 // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$sql="INSERT INTO traders (fname, lname, username)
VALUES
('$fname','$lname','$uname')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} 
echo "1 record added " ;

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two `action` in `form` tag - change 2nd to `method`

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br>
    Username:  <input type="text" name="uname" /><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"/><br>
</form>
```

because `method` was not found - it assumed GET.

Also instead of `$fname`, `$lname`, etc. use `$_POST['fname']`,`$_POST['lname']`, etc.

And learn more about binding variables into query

Comment: I originally had `$_POST['fname']` this format but wasn't working

Comment: because you had GET method ;)

Comment: oh, that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the POST method like this

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
```

Comment: I thought for a minute I was going crazy

Comment: @healix just get data with `$fname = $_POST['fname']` and every thing will be OK. Have a nice time!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change from

```
<form action="insert.php" action="post">
```

To...

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
```

Also.....you need to retrieve the values....

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'],  $lname = $_POST['lname'];  //etc etc
```

And do bound statements instead, for extra security...

Like so...

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('YOUR DETAILS HERE');


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO traders (fname, lname, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['uname']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: but the values still go into the table even without retrieving